# Can't map regular expression - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of capturing groups in the pattern segment

Tags: java, regex, spring-mvc

I have the following method defined in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/comments/post/{contentId:([apv]|ad)\\d+}")
    public @ResponseBody
    ActionResult handlePostCommentRequest(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
            @PathVariable("contentId") String assetId,
            @RequestParam(value = "nickName", required = false, defaultValue = "Anonyymi") String nickName,
            @RequestParam(value = "text", required = false, defaultValue = "") String text,
            @RequestParam(value = "createThread", required = false, defaultValue = "false") String createThread) {
            // some code...
}
```

However, when I do the following HTTP request - /ajax/comments/post/ad1374659405664 I get exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of capturing groups in
>   the pattern segment (([apv]|ad)\d+) does not match the number of URI
>   template variables it defines, which can occur if  capturing groups
>   are used in a URI template regex. Use non-capturing groups instead.

Google doesn't give that much results and it is weird, because when I check the regex 
    `([vpa]|ad)\d+`
in http://regexpal.com/ it matches everything correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you should escape your group inside the `@RequestMapping`? Try `(?:[apv]|ad)\\d+`. I think Spring creates a group for you which is enclosing the entire expression.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Everything is said in the error message: `use non-capturing groups instead`

```
(?:[apv]|ad)\\d+
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for further details.

Comment: Just to make it clear, for non-capturing groups, use (?:<regex expression>). The question mark and semi-colon after the opening bracket tell spring to not count the expression inside the brackets as another value to be assigned to a @PathVariable.